# openlayers Googlemap and custom wms

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps, wms

I have a custom wms server
the transform for this wms is UTM and i cannot set googlemap layr for background
for example my feature in wms is Iran country but googlemap background is Algeria

this is my code :

```
var options = {

        //maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(35.7008418592904, 51.3777884858342, 35.7520557036613, 51.4272609453396),
        //maxExtent:new OpenLayers.Bounds(506968.03125, 3936165,557431.4375, 3965082.5),
        units: "meters",
        format: "image/jpg",
        projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:2058"),
        displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
        numZoomLevels: 50
    };
function init() {
    var capaGoogle = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
               "Google Satellite",
               { sphericalMercator: true,projection:"EPSG:900913",
               transparent: true
               }
           );


    map = new OpenLayers.Map('MapDiv', options);
    wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                'WMS Layer Title',
                '../wms.ashx?dis=t',
                { layers: '', version: '1.3.0', srs: "EPSG:2058", transparent: true },
                { singleTile: true, ratio: 1, displayOutsideMaxExtent: true }
            );
     map.addLayers([wms, capaGoogle]);
 var lon = 3943679.05500279;
    var lat = 538414.111109505;

    var zoom = 11.3;

    center = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lat, lon);
    alert(center);
    map.setCenter(center, zoom);


}
```

i used transform like

```
center = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lat, lon).transform('EPSG:2058', 'EPSG:900913');
```

but that is not worked :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have multiple problems because of the way that your code has been set up.

- Firstly if the map contains a Google Layer, it needs to be set up with EPSG:3857 as the projection.
- Secondly, if you want to transform from a given lat-long to EPSG:3857, the following code should be sufficient:

  var geographic = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
  var mercator = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");
  center = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lat, lon).transform(geographic , mercator);
- Finaly, if you need to transform from 'EPSG:2058' to 'EPSG:900913', then you will need the proj4js library in your application, and you will need to set the EPSG:2058 projection using the proj4js string

You should also have a look at the following answer, which shows how you can have a wms in a different projection, on top of Google Maps:
[How to create a map with OSM and webatlas.de's WMS layer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59616/how-to-create-a-map-with-osm-and-webatlas-des-wms-layer/59624#59624)